# How does setTimeout work?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

-so i am obviously trying to get two functions to run automatically whilst on a timer using setTimeout. However i am not to sure how it works. All i can see when i search it up is it in a function. so how do i have it outside a function?

```
function ChangeImage() {
    if(position < TrafficL.length) {
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = TrafficL[position];
    position++
    }
}
function RestartPos() {
    if (position==3)
    document.getElementById("myImage").src = TrafficL["position"]
    position=0


    var setTimeout = (ChangeImage(),1500)
    var setTimeout = (RestartPos(),6000)
```

Comment: Read the documentation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

You sould call setTimeout as a function:

```
setTimeout(ChangeImage,1500);
setTimeout(RestartPos,6000);
```

`ChangeImage` and `RestartPos` are like variables referencing a function. If you place parentheses behind them means, you are calling them immediately, but you want to call them after a given time.

You can store the value return by `setTimeout()` in a variable though, but it's only for cancelling the countdown later:

```
// nothing happens, because the timeout was cancelled in 1.5s
var t = setTimeout(ChangeImage,1500);
clearTimeout(t);
```

Comment: I have actually fixed it now. i used setInterval instead of timeout and got rid of var.